# How to find video source url with simple_html_dom in Php

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I started learning php. How can I find video source url with php. Can someone tell me how to get video url with simple_html_dom? For example how to find a video source url from a website?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be more specific and show your attempts to us. What is the problem or what is the error that you got.

Comment: I want to learn how to access the source url of videos using simple_html_dom

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to understand how you can fetch an `HTML` document on a site. Everything you see in the browser consists of `HTML` and `CSS`. When you fetch a `HTML` document from a page with `PHP`, you get whatever is on the screen at that moment. So if a content is loaded into the page later using an `Ajax` call like below, **you can't get it** directly from the page.

```
function loadVideoURL() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("videosrc").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "get_video_url.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

In the current situation, suppose that the video urls included in the HTML document in the first place.

First Download latest version of simplehtmldom from [here](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/). This is the `PHP Class` to manipulate HTML in easy way and this library requires minimum `PHP 5`. Create a file which name is `simplehtmldomparser.php` in main directory of your project and include it using code below to your main `php` code.

```
<?php 
  include 'simplehtmldomparser.php';
?>
```

This code block will load the class to your main `PHP` file. Now, you want to fetch video url from the page.

```
<?php 
  $html = file_get_html('http://www.videos.com/'); 
  /* This line will fetch HTML document from the site that you wrote. */
?>
```

Now, you have the html document in `$html` variable. You need find video tags in HTML document. For example, If fetched page uses a `<video>` tag for videos, you can get the video urls as follows.

```
<?php
  foreach($html->find('video') as $element){
      echo $element->src . '<br>';
  }
?>
```

Here is another example that might work for your project. For example you want to jump another video in the website, fetch all `<a>` tags and get their `hrefs` and use the `$html = file_get_html($newlyfetchedanchor);` again. To fetch all `<a>` tags from the current `$html` use code below.

```
<?php
  foreach($html->find('a') as $element){
    echo $element->href;
  }
?>
```

There are more useful functions in the class and you can find [here](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm#section_access).

Comment: Kanka Türksün sende :) ismini yeni gördüm. Ben yeni başladım da. işin mantığını kavrayamadım bir türlü.